# Websocket application doesnt run in glassfish embedded, but runs in standalone version

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, glassfish-embedded

Good evening,

I have a simple websocket application. It runs fine if I deploy it to standalone glassfish server either using asadmin command or my IDE. When I use glassfish-**embedded**, everything seems fine (no error messages), but I get 404 at endpoint which should be serving websockets.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/test/websocket/zelitomasfds/efdsdfsdf' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Here is the code, should be pretty simple

```
/* Imports skipped */    

@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/{email}/{type}")
public class SimpleHOTPWebSocket {
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Received: " + message);
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, 
                       EndpointConfig c,
                       @PathParam("email") String email,
                       @PathParam("type") String type) {
        System.out.println("Client " + email + " connected as a " + type);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connection closed");
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

I've tried running it using webapp-runner and jetty as well, so problem must be somewhere in my code or pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cf.zelitomas</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplesocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>simplesocket</name>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>m.g.o-groups-glassfish</id>
            <url>http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>

                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <app>${project.build.directory}/${build.finalName}.war</app>
                    <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <contextRoot>test</contextRoot>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm starting server with `mvn clean install embedded-glassfish:run`

If you wanted to look at source code or try the war file, please feel free to download it here ([war](https://down.zelitomas.cf/simplesocket.war), [source](https://down.zelitomas.cf/simplesocket.zip))
Please, can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

*Thanks for your help, I'm struggling with this for more that 10 hours now.*

*And also sorry for my bad English*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>You mention glassfish-embedded in title, but you also mention you tried with jetty and webapp-runner, so I understand that in "embedded" mode you don't care about which you use.</sub>

So I downloaded your sources, tried it, reproduced the issue (same behavior), and... removed almost everything from the POM and added the required bits from scratch, using Jetty because I'm more familiar with it, and it only needs central maven repository (no repo added). Overall it's a lot simpler.

**Your code only needs a single dependency**: `javax.websocket-api`. All the rest is configuration for `jetty:run` (which I configured with context path "/test" to match your expectations, as default is "/").

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cf.zelitomas</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplesocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>simplesocket</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jetty-version>9.4.6.v20170531</jetty-version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/test</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

In short: replace your POM with the above, execute `mvn jetty:run`, and visit `http://localhost:8080/test`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you just saved me countless hours and few headaches. Just one additional question: do you have any idea what was wrong in original pom, so I can avoid same mistake next time?

Comment: Sorry no, yesterday I went directly to jetty, and today I also tried with embedded glassfish, with the same version, with newer versions too (websockets are supported from 3.1 so 3.0 would not work, and even 3.1 needs to explicitly enable them...), but no success, even with 4.0 or 4.1 :-/

Comment: Another nice thing with embedded jetty (compared to embedded Glassfish) is that you don't even need to build the war file to run your app.